# linux wildcard usage in cp and mv

Tags: linux, shell, cp, mv

I am composing a script to process 20 files. All of them located in different directories. I have partial file name.

1. In log directory, File1_Date_time.err change to File1__Date_time_orig.err
2. cd ../scripts/
3. sh File.sh

File1 directory is /data/data1directory/Sample_File1/logs/File1_Data_time.err
File2 directory is /data/data2directory/Sample_File2/logs/File2_Data_time.err
.....

My script looks like this. (runrunrun.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$1
mv /data/*/Sample_*/logs/*_Data_time.err /data/*/Sample_*/logs/*_Data_time_orig.err
cp /data/*/Sample_*/scripts/*.sh /data/*/Sample_*/scripts/*_orig.sh
sh /data/*/Sample_*/scripts/*_orig.sh
```

When running it, I tried.
./runrunrun.sh File1 
. runrunrun.sh File1 
sh runrunrun.sh File1

mv: cannot move `/data/data1directory/Sample_File1/logs/File1_Data_time.err /data/*/Sample_*/logs/*_Data_time_orig.err`: No such file or directory
cp also got similar feedback

Am I doing it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: `mv`, `cp`, etc. **aren't passed the wildcards you're writing**, if those wildcards have any valid expansions. Instead, they're passed literal filenames created by running those expansions. Thus, since they don't know the literal wildcards used in the input name, they can't possibly map a `*` in the input name to a `*` in the output name.

Comment: If you want to write renaming tools, a good place to start is BashFAQ #30: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629302/better-way-to-rename-files-based-on-multiple-patterns/25597051

Comment: BTW, `sh foo.sh` is **very dangerous**, unless you're absolutely certain that that script starts with `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/ksh`, `#!/bin/zsh`, etc; otherwise, it may use the wrong interpreter.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Let's talk about how wildcards work for a minute.

```
cp *.txt foo
```

doesn't actually invoke `cp` with an argument `*.txt`, if any files matching that glob exist. Instead, it runs something like this:

```
cp a.txt b.txt c.txt foo
```

Similarly, something like

```
mv *.txt *.old
```

...can't possibly know what to do, because when it's invoked, what it sees is:

```
mv a.txt b.txt c.txt *.old
```

or, worse, if you already *have* a file named `z.old`, it'll see:

```
mv a.txt b.txt c.txt z.old
```

---

Thus, you need to use different tools. Consider:

```
# REPLACES: mv /data/*/Sample_*/logs/*_Data_time.err /data/*/Sample_*/logs/*_Data_time_orig.err
for f in /data/*/Sample_*/logs/*_Data_time.err; do
  mv "$f" "${f%_Data_time.err}_Data_time_orig.err"
done

# REPLACES: cp /data/*/Sample_*/scripts/*.sh /data/*/Sample_*/scripts/*_orig.sh
for f in /data/*/Sample_*/scripts/*.sh; do
  cp "$f" "${f%.sh}_orig.sh"
done

# REPLACES: sh /data/*/Sample_*/scripts/*_orig.sh
for f in /data/*/Sample_*/scripts/*_orig.sh; do
  if [[ -e "$f" ]]; then
    # honor the script's shebang and let it choose an interpreter to use
    "$f"
  else
    # script is not executable, assume POSIX sh (not bash, ksh, etc)
    sh "$f"
  fi
done
```

This uses a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to strip off the tail end of the old name before adding the new name.

Comment: This is not the case anymore as of 2020 with GNU bash 5.0 and above

Comment: @user164863, please provide a contrary demonstration. `mv` and `cp` are not part of bash itself, they're provided by your OS vendor, and globs are already expanded before they're invoked; none of that has changed.

Answer (score 54):

The `find` command can be used quite concisely in simple cases where you want to perform operations on wildcard (or more complex) filename matches. The technique below can be committed to memory ... almost !

This works by letting the `find` command run another command on each filename it finds. You can dry-run this example using `echo` instead of/in front of `mv` .

If we wanted to move all files in the current directory with name beginning 'report', to another parallel directory called 'reports' :

```
find . -name "report*.*" -exec mv '{}' ../reports/ \;
```

The wildcard string must be in quotes, the {} marking the filename that was 'found' must be in quotes, and the final semicolon must be escaped - all due to Bash/shell treatment of those characters.

Look at the man page for `find` for more uses: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: if the file names of multiple files are the same, this solution seems to overwrite the files in the destination. How can the entire folder structure be copied over?

Comment: 1st answer covers my case. I also used cp --parents 
============================
for f in ./*/*20220202.csv; do
  cp -rfv --parents "$f" "/projects/drprojects/evmc/tempo4/" 
done

Comment: The code was just an example. The original question also had that problem.  Ask a separate question, or work it out !

Answer (score 7):

This is what I use, very fast to write and remember

For copying:

```
ls -1 *.txt | xargs -L1 -I{} cp {} {}.old
```

For moving:

```
ls -1 *.txt | xargs -L1 -I{} mv {} {}.old
```

the explanation:

```
xargs(1) -L1 -I{}
```

build and execute command lines from standard input

```
-L max-lines
       Use  at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.  Trailing blanks cause an input line
       to be logically continued on the next input line.  Implies -x.

-I replace-str
       Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from  standard  input.
       Also,  unquoted  blanks  do  not  terminate  input  items;  instead  the  separator is the newline
       character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

Basically with `-L1` it sends the arguments on by one, and `-I{}` makes `{}` the *placeholder*

Comment: Buggy with interesting filenames. In general, xargs is only safe with NUL-delimited input and the `-0` argument; default behavior splits input on spaces, not just newlines (though newlines aren't safe either, as they're allowed in filenames); treats quote characters as syntax rather than literal data; and otherwise generally munges input.

Comment: Also, see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 4):

using awk and sed

Filter using ls, use awk to build your move command for each record and the sed 'e' in the end will execute the command.

```
ls  *.avro  | awk ' { print "mv "$1" aa_"$1 }' | sed 'e'
```

First try without the sed -- once you know your command is showing correctly add the sed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change these:

```
zc_cd_delim_01.csv
zc_cd_delim_04.csv
```

into these:

```
zc_cd_delim_113_01.csv
zc_cd_delim_113_04.csv
```

command line:

```
for f in zc_cd_delim_??.csv; do var1=${f%%??.*}; 
    mv $f "${var1}113_${f#$var1}"; 
done
```

Comment: `mv "$f"`, rather -- if the `??` matches a filename with whitespace, or `IFS` contains a character found in the names (ie. `_`), behavior could otherwise be surprising.

Comment: BTW, I'm a little unclear on how this is applicable to the question at hand -- `c_cd_delim_??.csv` doesn't look to me like one of the patterns the OP was using as an example of what they wanted to match. Would you mind editing to make applicability to the question more clear?