# ubuntu cp: cannot stat <file>.tar.gz': no such file or dirctory

Tags: buildroot, imx6

I have looked through several posting on this, but still cannot find the correct answer. I am trying to make build root with a custom embedded chip tar file.
In the .config file the following is set:

BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOMER_TARBALL_LOCATION="file://~/linux....tar.gz"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION="custom"

Run 'make" and it works until the custom file is called. Then the error happens
cp: cannot stat '~/linux...tar.gz': No such file or directory

New to this whole build root and embedded linux world. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the related question and answer here:
[answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254164/what-is-cp-cannot-stat-error-in-unix-i-get-this-error-when-trying-to-copy-thin)
Not sure how to change from a hard coded path.. that is the next quest.

Answer (score 0):

No shell expansion is done on the `file://` URLs, so you can't use `~` to refer to your home directory. Either put the full path there, or use `${HOME}/linux....tar.gz`